# Restrict limit for user input on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, user-input

I want to implement an user input , which is restricted for just entering 4 characters. I could use the following code:

```
var userInput = readLine()
var newInput: String = "$userInput".take(4)
```

But I don't want that the user shall be able to enter more than 4 digits.
I saw that in Java there is a class called "BoundaryInputStream".
Is there also a solution for my problem in Kotlin ?

Comment: Assuming you're not writing a terminal application, you're most likely using some sort of user interface in between your user and the executable code of your inner logic. 

This migh be an Android project, in which case many of the available input widgets can be configured to limit the input size and content. 

For a web service, frameworks such as Spring Boot might offer input validation, e.g. through the means of 'Javax' annotations system. 

If you shed some more light on the context you're trying to implement this feature in, it might be easier to propose a natural, elegant solution.

Comment: If you don't find anything kotlin specific, you can always use Java from Kotlin.